# ControlSend Suppress Newlines When Sending Text to Notepad

Tags: autohotkey

I have a problem with ControlSend.When I am trying to send a text to notepad but ControlSend suppresses newlines.
For example
It sends to notepad the following:

```
> <p style="font-size:50px;font-weight:900"></p>
```

Instead of this:

```
> ++++ 
> <p style="font-size:50px;font-weight:900"></p>
> ++++
```

My code(Sorry for poor design):

```
append()
{ControlSend,Edit1,Clipboard,ahk_exe notepad.exe} ;Problem here

#If GetKeyState("Ctrl") && GetKeyState("Shift") 
{
e & h::
Title:= ""
InputBox, OutputVar ,"Title Level"
InputBox, HeadingName ,"Title Name"
if(OutputVar = 7)
{
Clipboard := "`n" . "++++" . "`n" . "<p style=""font-size:55px;font-weight:900"">" . HeadingName . "</p>" . "`n" . "++++" . "`n"
sleep 30
}

else if(OutputVar = 8)
{
Clipboard :="`n" . "++++" . "`n" . "<p style=""font-size:50px;font-weight:900"">++++" . HeadingName . "</p>" . "`n" . "++++" . "`n"
}

else if(OutputVar = 9)
{
Clipboard := "`n" . "++++" . "`n" . "<p style=""font-size:45px;font-weight:900"">" . HeadingName . "</p>" . "`n" . "++++" . "`n"
}

else if(OutputVar = 10)
{
Clipboard := "`n" . "++++" . "`n" . "<p style=""font-size:35px;font-weight:900"">" . HeadingName . "</p>" . "`n" . "++++" . "`n"
Sleep 30
}

else if(OutputVar = 11)
{
Clipboard := "`n" . "++++" . "`n" . "<p style=""font-size:30px;font-weight:900"">" . HeadingName . "</p>" . "`n" . "++++" . "`n"
}

else if(OutputVar = 12)
{
Clipboard := "`n" . "++++" . "`n" . "<p style=""font-size:25px;font-weight:900"">" . HeadingName . "</p>" . "`n" . "++++" . "`n"
}
sleep 30
append()
sleep 30
Return
;/...
}
```

I also have extra newline problem in Clipboard
For example:

It sends this :

```
> [source]
> ----  
> x                                                                                           
> 
> y
> 
> z
> ----
```

Instead of this:

```
> [source]
> ----  
> x                                                                                           
> y
> z
> ----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about Send in help.
+ is a special symbol, if you want send string "as is", use Raw mode of Send. Or enclose special symbols with {} braces.